# Fist vs. Hand Tracking Kinect SDK v1

Tags: visual-c++, kinect

I wanna track if I make a fist or if I have my hand open.

Like this shows:

> > http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Simple-Hand-Tracking-with-MS-Kinect-SDK--WPF

Now do I have the problem that I'm doing it in C++ and that in this example the old version of kinect is in used.

At first I've the problem to display just the hand in the depthView and then im going to have the problem to detect if it is a fist or a hand.

I'm looking forward for your help

Comment: Watch the video closely and you'll see the frames turn red even when the hands aren't closed. All they are doing is centering each frame around the hand "joint" and then summing up the pixels.  If # of pixels < some_threshold, hand = fist.  Whatever C++ SDK you're using will have a method for reading pixel color and depth.  If depth != 0 and pixel.color = black, pixels += pixel.

Comment: Kinect SDK v1.7 supports detection of gripped vs open hand through the interaction toolkit, not sure about c++ support though